# Gtk.Style.Font is obsolete?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Using gtk# on a cross platform application and trying to fix all the warnings, one of the warnings is that Gtk.Style.Font & Gdk.font is obsolete so can anybody point me to what replaced it?

All the google hits I get tell me to use Gtk.Style.Font etc... so hopefully somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that kind of cases, your best bet is to consult the [official API documentation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=P:Gtk.Style.Font):

> This is deprecated and should not be used in new code. New code should use `Style.FontDescription` instead.

If you are using an IDE, it would be a good idea to have the documentation handy.

Comment: argh. I can believe I missed such a simple solution. thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

For setting the font, use `x.ModifyFont(yourFontDescription)` (the property `x.Style.FontDescription` is read-only).